# System.Data.DataRowView when inserting to sql server

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to insert selected value from a listbox and the value is System.Data.DataRowView in the sql server, I'm kinda new to this vb thing. can you help...
why is that?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AccountsC20DataSet.ProductMast' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ProductMastTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AccountsC20DataSet.ProductMast)


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SAVE.Click

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = OMAR;Initial Catalog=AccountsC20;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ofamo;Password="
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con



            Dim Selected = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SInvoice  Values('" + Selected + "',0,1,1,1.000000,0.000000,'04/04/2019 08:45:08',0.000000,0.000000,'',0,1,1,1,1,'04/04/2019 08:45:08','',1.000000,1,0,'','b',0.000000,5,0.000000,0.000000,'Nos',1.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',0,3,'SIV-',1,1,1,1,1,1,0.000000)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try




    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

What i'm doing wrong here.....

Comment: That seems to suggest that you haven't set the `ValueMember` of the `ListBox`. The `DisplayMember` specifies the property/column of each item that gets displayed in the control and the `ValueMember` specifies the property/column that is exposed via the `SelectedValue` property. If what you actually want is the text displayed in the control for the selected item, use the `Text` property instead.

Comment: thanks @jmcilhinney